# Oversize Application - caused by AMPathPopUpButton

Tags: cocoa, xcode4.2

I have an application which I developed on Snow Leopard XCode 3.2 and I recently changed to Lion XCode 4.2

My compiled application jumped from 1.4MB to 10.3MB. While I have added some functionality this seemed excessive.

I examined the Package Contents and the problem seems to be one of the nib files (Preferences.nib) which has jumped from 20KB to 9MB, even though these has been no change to the xib file.

The nib contains the usual xml, but also some large chunks of data, several of which take 27,000 lines of xml
These share the following identity

```
        <key>$class</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CF$UID</key>
            <integer>186</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>NS.data</key>
```

Does anyone have any idea what is going on, or more importantly how to fix it?

**Edit**:
I have been experimenting, and opening the xib re-saves it as a 12MB file.
At least I have found what is causing the problem, I have 2 instances of AMPathPopUpButton, and if I delete these it reverts to a normal size.

PS I do have the Automator Framework linked.

Answer (score 0):

getting the parsing of a xib correct by removing pieces can become very problematic. I believe that your best bet would be to recreate the xib file and re link it to the class. Otherwise, if you have the app under source control you could checkout a previous version and diff the files.